# Custom Radio group with CSS when HTML is given

Tags: html, css, radio-group

I want to create a radio group which looks similar to this example from [Darin](https://codepen.io/dsenneff/pen/ZoLVZW)

[image: Custom Radio button]

The original sample uses a structure `<input ...><label>...</label>`, but the code generated by our app which I cannot change generates a nested `<label><input...></label>`.

How do I change the CSS to handle the nested code, without modifying the HTML?

**Html:**

```
<h3>
Modified code from darin: https://codepen.io/dsenneff/pen/ZoLVZW
</h3>
<fieldset>
    <div class="toggle">
        <input type="radio" name="sizeBy" value="weight" id="sizeWeight" checked="checked" />
        <label for="sizeWeight">It's prettygood</label>
        <input type="radio" name="sizeBy" value="dimensions" id="sizeDimensions" />
        <label for="sizeDimensions">100% yes</label>
        <input type="radio" name="sizeBy" value="super" id="super" />
        <label for="super">super</label>
    </div>
    <p class="status">Toggle is <span>auto width</span><span>full width</span>.</p>
</fieldset>


<h3>
My code that cannot be changed:
</h3>
<fieldset>
    <div class="toggle">
        <label for="sizeWeight">Prettygood
        <input type="radio" name="sizeBy" value="weight" id="sizeWeight" checked="checked" />
    </label>
        <label for="sizeDimensions">100% yes
         <input type="radio" name="sizeBy" value="dimensions" id="sizeDimensions" />
    </label>
        <label for="super">super
        <input type="radio" name="sizeBy" value="super" id="super" />
    </label>
    </div>
    <p class="status">Toggle is <span>auto width</span><span>full width</span>.</p>
</fieldset>
```

**SCSS:**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600'); 

/* VARS */
$open-sans: 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica', sans-serif;

$darkNavy: #213140;
$teal1: #66B3FB;
$teal2: #4B9DEA;
$charcoal: #555555;
$gold: #B6985A;

$activeShadow: 0 0 10px rgba($teal1, .5);

/* MIXINS */
@mixin focusOutline {outline: dotted 1px #CCC; outline-offset: .45rem;}
@mixin hideInput {width: 0; height: 0; position: absolute; left: -9999px;}
@mixin breakpoint($point) {
    @if $point == 1100 {
        @media (max-width: 1100px) { @content ; }
    }
    @else if $point == 800 {
        @media (max-width: 800px) { @content ; }
    }
}

/* STYLE THE HTML ELEMENTS (INCLUDES RESETS FOR THE DEFAULT FIELDSET AND LEGEND STYLES) */
body, html {
    margin: 0; padding: 1rem; box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    font-size: 16px; font-family: $open-sans; 
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    background-color: #EEE;
}
fieldset {
    margin: 0; padding: 2rem; 
    box-sizing: border-box; display: block;
    border: none; border: solid 1px #CCC;
    min-width: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    legend {
        margin: 0 0 1.5rem; padding: 0;
        width: 100%; float: left; display: table;
        font-size: 1.5rem; line-height: 140%; font-weight: 600; color: #333;    
        + * {clear: both;}
    }
}
body:not(:-moz-handler-blocked) fieldset {display: table-cell;}

/* TOGGLE STYLING */
.toggle {
    margin: 0 0 1.5rem; box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 0;
    display: flex; flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: flex-start; align-items: stretch;
    input {@include hideInput;}
    input + label {
        margin: 0; padding: .75rem 2rem; box-sizing: border-box;
        position: relative; display: inline-block;
        border: solid 1px #DDD; background-color: #FFF;
        font-size: 1rem; line-height: 140%; font-weight: 600; text-align: center;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(255,255,255,0);
        transition:     border-color .15s ease-out, 
                    color .25s ease-out, 
                    background-color .15s ease-out,
                    box-shadow .15s ease-out;

        /* ADD THESE PROPERTIES TO SWITCH FROM AUTO WIDTH TO FULL WIDTH */
        /*flex: 0 0 50%; display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;*/
        /* ----- */

        &:first-of-type {border-radius: 6px 0 0 6px; border-right: none;}
        &:last-of-type {border-radius: 0 6px 6px 0; border-left: none;}
    }
    input:hover + label {border-color: $darkNavy;}
    input:checked + label {
        background-color: $teal2;
        color: #FFF;
        box-shadow: $activeShadow;
        border-color: $teal2;
        z-index: 1;
    }
    input:focus + label {@include focusOutline;}

    @include breakpoint(800) {
        input + label {
            padding: .75rem .25rem;
            flex: 0 0 50%;
            display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;
        }
    }
}

/* STYLING FOR THE STATUS HELPER TEXT FOR THE DEMO */
.status {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1rem; font-weight: 400;
    span {
        font-weight: 600; color: $gold;
        &:first-of-type {display: inline;}
        &:last-of-type {display: none;}
    }
    @include breakpoint(800) {
        span {
            &:first-of-type {display: none;}
            &:last-of-type {display: inline;}           
        }
    }
}
```

My [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dmenne/cm0douq6/33/)

Comment: You're not going be able to accomplish that design with that semantic structure of your HTML with CSS alone simply because of the natural order of inception of **cascading** style sheets. In other words input:checked -> label{stuff} works as shown in your desired example because it's one way. However label{stuff} <- input:checked will not since it's in reverse of the natural order by spec. Could either change your html output accordingly, or write some javascript to help with parent/child node handling and manually supply class changes.

Comment: Although @ChrisW. is correct about the CSS limitations, the `input` nested in the `label` tag makes for simple implicit binding of the elements. You should be able to achieve something similar by applying a class to the `label` element that wraps the currently selected `input` (would need some JS added to do so)

Comment: @Chris W. Thanks for explaining why my attempts to `label{stuff}<-input` failed